# How use full page width for a paragraph using the moderncv class

Tags: xetex, moderncv

Is there a way to use the full page width for a specific section in the `moderncv`class?
For example, for the section below, how can I make the executive summary paragraph occupy  the whole red box below?

[image: Example of paragraph]

I am using the following code for this paragraph:

```latex
\cvitem{}{
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet ligula nec orci commodo, a suscipit eros euismod. Nullam sed quam at sapien tincidunt vehicula. Quisque nec metus ac ipsum pharetra consequat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus vel erat non lorem.
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, do not use `\cvitem`

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{moderncv}

\moderncvtheme[blue]{casual}

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}

\begin{document}
    \maketitle
    \section{Executive Summary}
    
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed aliquet ligula nec orci commodo, a suscipit eros euismod. Nullam sed quam at sapien tincidunt vehicula. Quisque nec metus ac ipsum pharetra consequat. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Vivamus vel erat non lorem.
        
\end{document}
```